# How to remove the "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer" error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this code which creates a NaT value in the 4th row of the feature:

```
print(df['Date'][3])
df['Date'][3] = np.datetime64("NaT")
print(df['Date'][3])
```

[Output shows that it is a NaT value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyvoi.png)

This is the code in the next cell:

```
nat=np.datetime64('NaT')
for i in Dates:
    for value in df[i]:
        print(value)
        if np.isnat(value):
            df.loc[i, value] = df[i].mode()
            print(value)
```

But this is throwing the error:

```
    4 for value in df[i]:
      5     print(value)
----> 6     if np.isnat(np.datetime64(value)):
      7         df.loc[i, value] = df[i].mode()
      8         print(value)
```

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

[Error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5dLz.png)

Why is this error coming? I cannot compare if I remove 'np.datetime64(___)'. But with it, NaT is not being compared. What shall I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Nan values are considered floats but aren't an actual number so you can't convert it to an int. But it looks like you're trying to fill nan values with the mode? You should be able to do something like df.fillna(df[dates'].mode())

Comment: @rayad Yes I want to fill the values. Won't this method you mentioned fill all the null values of the dataset with that particular column's mode value?